# Python-Flask: Can a front-end client receive data streaming from a websocket connected to some company's service?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I have a dashboard with data that I would like updated in real-time from a subscribed websocket
channel. I am currently using Flask and get updated data with request and response cycles.

I am investigating Flask-SocketIO, but can't seem to figure out how to connect a websocket
feed from Alpaca (the datasource) and get that data to my dashboard webclient.

Would the data flow from 1) Alapca => Flask => webclient? or 2) Alpaca => webclient => Flask => webclient?

I would prefer case (1) because I want to do some processing and also because I have just started dabbling with javascript for the first time for this project (but whatever works determine the choice).

What packages or libraries would you use to accomplish this? How would you do it? (I'm on a windows pc)

I currently have a file that runs the flask app on one port and another file that connects to the
data source that streams the data on another port. How do you connect the two? Can both Flask-SocketIO and Alpaca listen/stream data on the same port? I looked around and can't find any examples that help. Can it be done?

This doesn't seem kosher, but could something like the following be done?

```
# Alpaca websocket connection: data inflow
@conn.on(r'^T.*$')
async def on_data(conn, channel, data):
    data_dict = data._raw
    print('data:', data_dict)

    # FastAPI websocket creation: pass-through/ data outflow
    @app.websocket("/ws")
    async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()

        while True:
            payload = data_dict 
            await websocket.send_json(payload)


conn.run(['T.AAPL']])
```

Can something like this be accomplished using Flask-SocketIO?

References:
[Connecting to Alpaca websocket](https://forum.alpaca.markets/t/getting-live-data/996/5)
[Creating websocket using FastAPI](https://stribny.name/blog/2020/07/real-time-data-streaming-using-fastapi-and-websockets/)

Comment: You need to add some details about how you connect to this Alpaca service. Is it also Socket.IO or some other protocol?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Miguel.  I imported StreamConn, which I found from https://algotrading101.com/learn/alpaca-trading-api-guide/.  Alpaca says that they follow the RFC6455 WebSocket protocol. I'm a novice so I'm not familiar with the protocol. I have not imported Socket.IO on the webclient side and I have not implemented Flask-SocketIO on the server side either because I'm stuck trying to figure out how to pass the data/stream from Alpaca to my front-end. Any clues would be awesome.